# Operating point for high current transistors

Tags: transistors, amplifier, npn, common-emitter, common-collector

I'm a neophyte self-thaught learning electronics. I'm trying to amplify a DC current from a little less than 1 to 8 A using an NPN transistor. Currently I'm trying to figure out how even could I accomplish that: I'm searching for a transistor which can handle a 1 A collector current. For example the [TIP47](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tip47.pdf). The problem is that, reading the datasheet, I couldn't find the output graphs Vce - Ic for different values of Ib (where c, e, b denote collector emitter and base).
Therefore how could I determine the working point?

Moreover, since the functioning concept feels a little obscure yet, can anyone explain or point me to some source on how does a transistor amplifier works?

P.S.: thanks a lot in advance for any answers and excuse my English: I'm still learning it!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139744/discussion-on-question-by-luke-operating-point-for-high-current-transistors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a current driver (10A).
It can be used as a PWM drive (variable Duty) or a static voltage.

[image]

And with a number (16 paralleled) of TIP47 (~ 0.7 A max, very high voltage devices 250 V ...).
NB: a low serial resistor for each Emitter of the paralleled transistors is to be used, to be sure that "Ie current" is the "same" for all BJT.

[image]

Comment: It seems he was looking to design with TIP47 transistor. You had used a MOSFET.

Comment: The maximum Ic current of TIP47 is only 1 A. The OP needs at least 8 A ... Thus, not suitable for the application unless paralleling a number of these devices (12 -> 16 at least ... and a driver added). An IRF540 or similar could do the job alone (a "big" heatsink is needed, however). Will try with "multiple" TIP47.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Moreover, TIP47 is a "high" voltage BJT. Very special device.

Comment: Ok. Not so difficult as I thought ... Will add a new schematic in the answer.

Comment: It seems that TIP47 transistor was a bad choice for the design. its colector peak current is just 2A.